# No performance gain after enabling Opcode caching

Tags: php, caching, optimization, opcode

I have a bunch of php services running behind the message queue and my symfony controller are accessing these services to get the data. I am doing some benchmark testing to evaluate the performance of Opcode caching. The problem is that the performance gain I am attaining after enabling any of the Opcode caching (zend opcache or apc) is negligible. I am using 'ab' utility for benchmark testing.

So the total response time (without any opcode caching) is 66 seconds and the same for zend opcode cache is 54 seconds. The total response time in case of APC is 64 seconds. I am making 50000 request with no concurrent request for the benchmarking.

Please any advice what could be preventing the Opcode caching to gain significant performance.

**EDIT 1**
Call to the `apc_cache_info()` returns the following:

```
array (size=14)
  'nslots' => int 4099
  'ttl' => int 0
  'nhits' => float 0
  'nmisses' => float 0
  'ninserts' => float 0
  'nentries' => int 0
  'nexpunges' => float 0
  'stime' => int 1404812585
  'mem_size' => float 0
  'file_upload_progress' => int 1
  'memory_type' => string 'mmap' (length=4)
  'cache_list' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'deleted_list' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'slot_distribution' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Comment: OMG! Symfony *and* Zend Framework? You really don't want your code to run fast, do you? Have you checked what's in the cache? If it's sized correctly?

Comment: no, my project is only Symfony based... I am using zend opcode caching. I will check the cache size and whats in there

Answer (score 1):

Any Opcode cache should speed up a Symfony app by *at least* 2x.  So step one is to forget symphony for a bit, and just make sure that you've got the cache running properly.

Have you correctly configured your web stack?.  `phpinfo()` should confirm that you are running `Apache 2.0 Handler` for example and that the cache is enabled.  Then you need to configure the INI settings correctly.  APC includes a nice web front end and Rasmus has done a cutdown equivalent for OPcache.  Only when you are caching your `phpinfo.php` should you then start looking at your Sympfony app.

Answer (score -2):

Let us demean the user with suggestions like check phpinfo(); let us assume that opcache is enabled.... I have tried opcache enabled for a number of different applications and have noticed no optimisation in performance.... In fact in some circumstances with opcache the scripts run even slower.... I have tried to switch off to change  opcache.revalidate_freq and even switched off opcache.validate_timestamps to see if those setting would improve things but no..... So in conclusion to me opcache DOES NOT optimise performance in anyway.

Comment: You should at least share some credible sources for your claim

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).